# Unity, Calling a IEnumerator function from Button onClick

Tags: function, unity-game-engine, onclick, buttonclick, ienumerator

I tried to call a `IEnumerator` function from button click so I could yield return something, but I can't choose the function from the inspector's `On Click()` dropdown menu.

I tried to call the `IEnumerator` from another function and assign that function to the button, doesn't work!

And apparently I can't do `yield return` in a `void` function.

So could somebody please be so kind and teach me what should I do!?

Much appreciated!

Comment: No you cant do yield return on a void - its void it has no return

Comment: Is your IEnumerator a coroutine basically?

Comment: you can do `yield return null;` tho

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a certain rules to hook a function to a unity event from the inspector.

1) The function must be `public` to be able to choose it from the inspector.

2) The return type must be `void`, so you won't be able to choose functions with any return type, and since your `IEnumerator` function returns an `IEnumerator`, you won't be able to choose it from the inspector.

3) The function parameters must match the event parameters unless the UnityEvent doesn't take any parameters like Button.onClick event (thanks @derHugo for correcting), for example the button `onClick` event doesn't take any parameters, so to choose a function for it from the inspector the function must look like

```
public void ChoosableTemplateForOnClickButton() { }
```

But you want to call an IEnumerator from the inspector, so what you can do is wrap it in a void function:

assuming your IEnumerator function looks like

```
public IEnumerator MyRoutine()
{
   yield and enjoy...
}
```

wrap it in a void function:

```
public void RoutineWrap()
{
   StartCoroutine(MyRoutine());
}
```

Now you can choose `RoutineWrap` from the inspector.

Comment: The point `3) The function parameters must match the event parameters,` is not quite correct! `UnityEvent` allows to add either **static** parameter methods (with `0` or `1` parameter and limitted to the basic types (`float`, `string`, `bool`, `int`, etc and `Object` references)) or you can add **dynamic** parameter methods. Here in case of `onClick` there are none but you can implement you custom `UnityEvent<T>` with multiple dynamic parameters ;)

Comment: True, but eventually to hook a method to an event from the 'inspector', the signatures (parameters) must match, i.e an event with (bool,string) parameters can only choose functions with (bool,string) parameters from the inspector dropdown, which is what I said, I'm saying the event only sees functions matching its parameters, didn't say it can't have multiple parameters :D

Comment: And that's where I said it's not true ;) in a normal `UnityEvent` like `Button.onClick` you can still reference methods as said with either none or one basic type as parameter and pass it in static.

Comment: Oh, oh yes I got your point now, that is true, I'll edit the statement to be `The function parameters must match the event parameters, unless the event is parameterless.`

Answer (score 2):

Alternative to [this correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58392633/7111561) you can always also add the callback on runtime via script.

Still in Unity every Coroutine has to be started using `StartCoroutine`:

```
public Button button;

private void Awake()
{
    button.onClick.AddListener(() => StartCoroutine(MyRoutine()));
}

private IEnumerator MyRoutine()
{
    ...
}
```